# Efficient Algo for Removal of Duplicates from a Complex Structure - A part of Krushkal's Algorithm for MST

Tags: java, algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I have an `ArrayList<Edge>` in which I have to remove duplicate values. 
`Edge` class is as follows

```
class Edge
{
    int srcNode;
    int destNode;
    double edgeWeight;
}
```

I wan to calculate **Minimum Spanning Tree** of a Graph to implement **Krushkal's algorithm**.  To calculate that I will have to remove all the duplicate `Edge`s from a list. So **which algorithm would be best suitable to remove duplicate values** from this kind of Data Structure with srcNode, destNode and edgeWeight.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a different data structure and impose an ordering on the vertices so that each edge is represented in exactly one way?

Comment: All three things src, dest and weight should be same to qualify as duplicate. At least src and dest should be there to remove duplicate. I can not rely alone on the weight which can be same for more edges. All things seems to be mandatory.

Comment: put them in a `Set<Edge>` and implement `.equals()` & `hashCode()`, see which edges survive?

Comment: @MasterJ

Fair enough, but is there any reason why you can't use something like a `Set` that inherently doesn't allow duplicates?

Comment: @DennisMeng I can use sets but someone has implemented it for us. If I will use that, that would not be the part of my learning. I must implement it on my own so that I will understand how set kind of data structure works.

Comment: Ah, sounds reasonable.

Comment: If you want to implement a hash based set on your own have a look at [WP:Hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or the source of [HashMap](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29). `HashSet` is simply a `HashMap` without values - just keys.

Comment: However this data structure helps in Constant time retrieval of values but still how would I write code to remove duplicates from this HashSet(In case I write my own) too?

Comment: insertion is O(1) on average. If just put a whole list of N edges in there you end up with unique items in O(N).

Comment: You don't need to remove duplicates before running Kruskal.

Comment: Agree with @DavidEisenstat. Kruska's MST (Minimum Spanning Tree) algorithm has no problems with duplicate edges.

Comment: If I will not remove duplicates then algorithm will consider next encountered duplicate edge as not exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a binary search tree of `Edges` on the basis of `edgeWeight`. While inserting in BST keep one thing in mind is to check if Edge with edgeWeight is already present in BST (compare srcNode and destNode too), if it is found then discard it else add it to BST. In this way you will be having all unique Edges in BST.

 
 
searching in BST will take only log(n) time (n=number of element in BST).
if number of edges are 'm' then complexity would be m log(n)

> PS: I'm assuming  from srcNode '1' to destNode '2' will have duplicate Edges with same edgeWeight. if you have multiple edges with different edgeWeight on two node then you can choose the minimum one and replace it in BST while inserting if it already present. In this way you will have lowest edgeWeight for that Edge

Comment: Yes, this is good enough. It can work certainly; let me implement it first.

Comment: What will you do when weight of two Edges comes same. Ambiguity comes here.

Comment: If the weight is same check if srcNode and destNode are different, If they are different then add that edgeWeight. In a BST you can keep duplicate edgeWeight

Comment: I have implemented the Tree based duplicate removal algorithm. Which is very efficient; it removes duplicates from 10000 elements in just 150 milliseconds.

Comment: http://jakharmania.blogspot.in/2013/08/duplicate-removal-from-list-this.html

Here is my implementation. It works correctly with logarithmic time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

like @zapl has said, you can use `Set`.

anyway, you have to sort the edges, why don't you consider implement `compareTo`, then sort the edges, then if one edge equals the previous one, skip it.

see: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

btw, Krushkal doesn't require the edges to be unique, the second time an edge is processed, fa[u] would equal fa[v] and this edge would be ignored.